# element.all couldn't list the locator

Tags: javascript, css, protractor

[the code to be tested is shown in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2Doa.jpg)

I'musing element.all but the list is getting empty, e.g.

```
element.all(by.css('[ng-bind="premiseObj.address"]')).then(function(items){
    console.log("Total values in dropdown are: " + items.length);
```

...

the rresult is: Total values in dropdown are: 0
the number of items in the list, it should be 2!

or another examples;

```
element.all(by.binding('premiseObj\.address')).then(function(items)
```

or

```
element.all(by.repeater('premiseObj in contractsObj\.premiseList')).last().getWebElement().then(function(item)
```

None of these examples are working since the list is empty.

Protractor 3.3.0, webdriver-manager 2.21.

Thanks
hassand

Comment: in those cases that binding or repeater are used the errors are different and protractor fails to locate the selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't it work:

```
element.all(by.repeater('premiseObj.address')).count().then(function(items){
    console.log("Total values in dropdown are: " + items);
}
```

You don't need to escape the '.' in the locator.

Comment: Thanks flaviomeira10 for your reply. It's the same fault with the "dot" escaped or not escaped, it failed to locate the selectors.

Comment: No, it's not working neither. The result was: Total values in dropdown are: undefined

Comment: It used the binding locator instead of the repeater. Try with the repeater locator.

Answer (score 0):

`by.repeater()` should be a preferred locator in this situation:

```
var premises = element.all(by.repeater('premiseObj in contractsObj.premiseList'));
expect(premises.count()).toEqual(2);
```

You *don't need to escape the dots* in the repeater string.

Comment: Thanks alecxe for your reply. No, it's still the same error as before "Expected 0 to equal 2".

Comment: @hassand okay, just to check, what if you add `browser.sleep(3000)` before searching for the elements? Thanks. (note: if it helps, it is not the best solution)

Comment: It didn't help at all to delay 3 to 10 sec neither. items.length is undefined.

Comment: if I add a browser.sleep(1000);
and change the locator to 

`element.all(by.css('[ng-repeat="premiseObj in contractsObj.premiseList"]')).then(function(items){
  console.log("Total values in dropdown are: " + items.length);
});`

this will work, but not without waiting 1 sec.

Comment: `element.all(by.css('[ng-repeat="premiseObj in contractsObj.premiseList"]')).last().getWebElement().then(function(addField){
 browser.sleep(3000);
 console.log("The address is: " + addField.getText());
});`
the result became the follwoing error message, that I've no clue what it means.

**The address is: ManagedPromise::1015 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}**

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused by omitting the ignoresynchronization = false; after testing the non angular part of code.

but the `browser.sleep(1000)`still needed before using
`element.all(by.repeater('premiseObj in contractsObj.premiseList'));`